# Why don't I have the right to create a text file in my root directory?

Tags: windows-7, privileges

When I right-click in a window showing my C:\ directory in Windows 7 and try to create a new text file, I get an error message: "A required privilege is not held by the client."  Why is this and how can I change it?

Comment: Can you do it from an elevated notepad? Explorer.exe is not elevated.

Comment: Yes I can.  My question is, why has my root directory been made less accessible in this way?

Comment: Because if you can access your root, so can IAmAVirus.exe! It's a good thing, honest.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The C: drive is protected from modification by normal users. Unless your an administrator or can elevate another process to administrator, you won't be able to write to C: drive except in your C:/Users/ folder.

**More Info**

IF you right click C: in the Computer view, go to security, you'll notice that you won't have Write permissions. You get Read/Execute, List Files, and Read.

Comment: I am an administrator - this is my own laptop.  Is there no way to lift the protection?

Comment: You can try to add Full Access as a permission for your account. But it is not recommended. If you need to store a file somewhere, the best place is on another drive, or in your users folder.

Comment: You need to add Full Access to your account on C:\. Since Vista, this directory is protected, as it's one of the favorite places for viruses. In any case, too many irreplaceable system files reside there.

Comment: I understand Phoshi's point that a virus could pose as a user, but I've experimentally granted myself Write permission in C:\\.  I still can't create a text file from Explorer, though.

Comment: You need full access to create a file, iirc.

Comment: I think I did have it, but I'll give up now.  Thanks for your advice.

Comment: yep, write only lets you write to existing files for... I'm sure a very good reason, but I don't know what is it.

Comment: I'm sorry that you're unable to give yourself access the the C: drive.  It was secured by Microsoft so that viruses have a harder time of burying themselves into the OS on a regular user account. As for recommended solutions, if you have another drive, put the file there, or place it in your My Documents folder.

Answer (score 0):

To fix it, just turn off the User Account Control (UAC). In Windows 8, do not turn off the UAC via control panel, it must go through the registry.

```
Press keys “Windows Key + R”, type regedit
Locate HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System\EnableLUA
Update the EnableLUA value to 0 (turn if off)
Restart Windows.
```